# Failed to start selenoid

Tags: windows, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, selenoid

I have downloaded wsl2 and curl on my Windows 10, then downloaded docker with this command:

`curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com | sudo bash -s`

next step I started docker deamon with: `dockerd`, installed selenium.exe from official page and tried this command: `D:\path\to\selenoid.exe selenoid start --vnc --browsers "chrome:69.0" --args "-limit 1000" --force`

But I got this error:

`Failed to initialize: [can not access Docker: make sure you have Docker installed and current user has access permissions]`

I was getting the same error while using docker desktop and not starting deamon, but as far as I know, by using command `dockerd` with root, deamon should start, so i don`t know what can be the problem

(in my case I can`t use docker desktop, if there is another way to download docker from terminal or just by one .exe, please tell me)

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you cannot use Docker Desktop? Have you read and attempted to follow the instructions on using Docker with the WSL2 backend here? https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong binary. Should use [CM](https://github.com/aerokube/cm/) tool instead of Selenoid.